# Как преобразовать строку чтобы получился список

Tags: python, list

Есть строка:

```
'[{"account_id": 14787082, "role_name": null, "clan_id": null, "in_clan_cooldown_till": "2016-12-11T18:42:40.677684", "joined_at": "2016-11-06T06:00:17.068401", "status": "active"}, {"account_id": 23414687, "role_name": "commander", "clan_id": 11010, "clan_tag": "CLEAR", "joined_at": "2016-04-04T15:05:24.080961", "status": "active", "in_clan_cooldown_till": "2015-11-03T15:22:44.843015", "role_bw_flag": 1}]'
```

Как преобразовать её в список,чтобы можно было итерироваться по json объектам?

Answer (score 3):

Если это `json`, то и обращаться надо как с `json`:

```
import json

a = '[{"account_id": 14787082, "role_name": null, "clan_id": null, "in_clan_cooldown_till": "2016-12-11T18:42:40.677684", "joined_at": "2016-11-06T06:00:17.068401", "status": "active"}, {"account_id": 23414687, "role_name": "commander", "clan_id": 11010, "clan_tag": "CLEAR", "joined_at": "2016-04-04T15:05:24.080961", "status": "active", "in_clan_cooldown_till": "2015-11-03T15:22:44.843015", "role_bw_flag": 1}]'
j = json.loads(a)
for acc in j:
    for el in acc:
        print(el, acc[el])
```

Comment: Вид правильной конструкции - [{},{}] то-есть это список json объектов. А конструкция сейчас в таком виде - '[{},{}]' для начала нужно из строки достать список а затем итерироваться и раздумпливать каждуый объект. Задача вытащить список из строки. А что делать с Json я в курсе

Comment: @Import_Mozg Ну вообще-то список - это тоже корректный объект JSON, насколько я понимаю, так что можете спокойно грузить всю строку как JSON, мой код вполне работает и сначала итерируется по элементам списка, а потом по словарям внутри списка. Я, кстати, проверил - так получается именно питоновский список и питоновские словари.

Comment: Возможно не верно изложил вопрос. Вообщем есть строка - '[]' как получить/преобразовать тип str, чтобы получить тип list

Comment: @Import_Mozg, у j в ответе тип list

Comment: @Import_Mozg Есть другой способ - через `literal_eval` или даже просто `eval`, но раз у вас корректный `json` внутри, вам лучше взять таки `json.loads`, поверьте мне. Потому что `eval` хоть и работает, но его использование не безопасно, а у `literal_eval` много странных проблем бывает, вашу строку он не парсит всё-равно.

Comment: Кстати, `json.loads` ещё и корректно `null` в `None` превращает сам. У `eval` с `null` будут проблемы.

Comment: literal_eval и eval  выдают ошибку - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    eval(a)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: @Import_Mozg Объясните, почему вы не хотите использовать `json.loads`? Вы в итоге получите тоже самое, но сложным и длинным путём. Чтобы починить `eval` можно сделать заранее переменную `null = None`, а `literal_eval` починить сложнее.

Comment: Уже использую ), не нашел пока альтернативы, спасибо за ответ